Why won't tmux let me search scrollback for certain strings anymore?
Something has recently changed about tmux or the software that I'm running within it such that I can no longer reliably search through its output in the scrollback. Some strings are searchable and some are not, and I have no idea what the difference is except that I have a wild suspicion it might have something to do with colors on nearby lines.
For example I currently have this on my screen:

I can use Ctrl-A, ? to do a search up for Build and time to find those strings; it works fine. But if I search for Elapsed there are no results, or at least it's not highlighted.
If I use capture-pane and save-buffer to save the scrollback, there is nothing weird about the string Elapsed as far as I can tell.
I am using Terminal.app on macOS, SSH'd to a Linux machine running tmux.
How in the world do I go about debugging this problem?

This is apparently a known issue with tmux 3.4.
